# iOS 16 collectionView layoutAttributesForItem return the wrong size with estimated height compositional layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, ios16, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I ran into an ios 16 problem when `layoutAttributesForItem` returns a very small cell size if it is far beyond the scope and visibility and has not yet been seen.

I'm using compositional layout with `estimated(1)` and it feels like its real size is not calculated before it appears on the screen

So I set the section:

`

```
     func getListLayout() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(1)
        )
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(1)
        )

        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: groupSize,
            subitem: item,
            count: 1
        )

        group.contentInsets = .zero

        let headerFooterSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(headerHeight)
        )

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = .zero
        section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionHeader]

        return section
    }
```

Wrong result with:

```
let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
attributes.frame.minY
```

*IOS 14-15* everything works well..

I noticed that if you set a specific height for the cell (absolute), everything works as it should, but I need the height to be considered dynamically.
Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Mp5.jpg)